# Steam characters

Tags: steam

During big sales or special deals, Steam changes its background images to those containing their own characters:

[image]
[image]
Who are these guys? What are their names? How can we be friends?

Answer (score 7):

## Tappet

[image: Tappet]
Tappet is the orange Steam mascot with adjustable antenna horns.

## Cyl

[image: Cyl]
Cyl is the cynical, mischievous, dark mascot.

## Sir Roderick Bodkin

[image: Sir Roderick Bodkin]
Sir Roderick Bodkin is the happy yellow hazmat suit mascot.

---

The other three appear less often, and I can't find any information on their names.